# Profiling a Go program spanning several runs

Tags: go, profiling

I want to profile a Go program's performance between different runs with different OS-level settings. I'm aware that I can get profiles for single runs via `$ go test -cpuprofile cpu.prof -memprofile mem.prof -bench .`. However I don't know how to aggregate the information in such a way that I can compare the results either visually or programmatically.

To present a sketch in [Xonsh](https://xon.sh) scripting language, which is a creole between Python and Bash. However I'm happy to accept suggestion written in pure Bash as well.

```
for i in range(n):
    change_system_settings()
    # Run 'go test' and save the results in cpu0.prof, cpu1.prof, cpu2.prof etc. 
    @(f'go test -cpuprofile cpu{i}.prof -memprofile mem{i}.prof -bench .'.split())
```

The script changes the system settings and runs the program through profiler n times. Now, after the process I'm left with possibly dozens of individual `.prof` files. I would like to have a holistic view of them, compare the memory and CPU usage between runs and even run numeric tests to see which run was optimal.

Comment: `go test -count 15` for n == 15.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? That command appears to run the tests 15 (or n) times. However I want to profile the program across these runs with different OS-level settings I can adjust with a CL function, called `change_system_settings()` in OP. Or alternatively by an executable `change_system_settings` in `PATH` if that makes more sense to you.

Comment: Okay, understood. You cannot do what you want. Sorry.

Comment: No probz. Could have been more explicit in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

If you use GoLang's `pprof` to profile your Go program, the library has a `Merge` method that merges multiple pprof output files into one.

The library is github.com/google/pprof, so you just import it in a Go script:

```
import ('github.com/google/pprof/profile')
```

Then you'll need to load all your pprof files into one array. If we consider that you did that and you have all your files loaded (using os.Open()) in an array called allFiles, you merge them using the following method:

```
result, err := profile.Merge(allFiles)
```

Then you output the merged data into a new file, using os.OpenFile(...), writing to this file, then closing it.

I haven't tested this right now honestly, but I remember this is how we did it a long time ago. So technically, you could invoke this golang script after your `for` loop is done in your test script.

Documentation: https://github.com/google/pprof/blob/master/doc/README.md

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this later and mark as the answer if it works.